# Accessing static function in separate file from main()

Tags: c, pointers, linker

I have hello.c containing a function hello():

```
#include <stdio.h>
static void hello() {
   printf("hello.\n");
}
```

Now, I have main() in main.c, from which I want to call hello() residing in hello.c. 
I think I have to pass a function pointer from hello.c to a function in main.c, but I don't know how how to do that exactly. An example with an explanation on how to link the two files would be great! Thanks.

Comment: doesnt that defy the purpose of static?

Comment: Have you tried to use a header file to declare (not implement) `hello()` in it and then  include it from main.c??

Comment: You see it in plenty of projects written in C, just have a look at some at GitHub. Some special function is declared as static in module_xyz.c and then exposed to main() somehow.

Comment: Well, you don't have to do anything special for it to work, but it is usually bad style, and this will trigger a warning (implicit declaration).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

***hello.h***

```
#ifndef INCLUDED_HELLO_H
#define INCLUDED_HELLO_H

void (*get_hello(void))(void);

// or, better:
// typdef void(*funcptr)(void);
// funcptr get_hello(void);

#endif
```

***hello.c***

```
#include "hello.h"
#include <stdio.h>

static void hello(void) {
  puts("Hello!");
}

void (*get_hello(void))(void) {
  return hello;
}
```

***main.c***

```
#include "hello.h"

int main(void) {
  void(*hello)(void) = get_hello();
  hello();
  get_hello()();
}
```

EDIT:

As was quite correctly pointed out to me (sorry, I am new here), this is not exactly self-explaining. Well, the confusing bit is really only the syntax. What we're dealing with here are **function pointers**. They are exactly what it says on the tin: Pointers to functions, through which functions may be called. The syntax is off-putting, which is why typedefs are your friend, but there you are.

`hello` in `main` is a function pointer variable; it's a pointer to a function returning nothing and taking nothing.

`get_hello` is a function taking no arguments returning a pointer to a function returning nothing and taking no arguments. Similarly,

```
`int (*foo(double))(float);
```

would delare a function foo taking a double and returning a pointer to a function taking a float and returning an int.

And, well, that's all there is to it. It is, in principle, very simple, and only the horrible syntax makes it look complicated.

Comment: The Question also asked "with an explanation", which is also expected as a standard for good quality answer on this site, without this, some code only answer get closed and removed.